# How to render a database with javascript

Tags: javascript, database, sqlite, loops, while-loop

I was wondering if anyone could be of some assistance to me.

I'm trying to render tables from the application database of an app I've created with TideSDK.

So it'd render each table on the same page with all rows/columns. I think I'm on the right track, incorporating a WHILE loop inside a WHILE loop.

This is my JS code:

```
window.onload = function () { 

//connect to application database
var db = Ti.Database.openFile(Ti.Filesystem.getFile(
                          Ti.Filesystem.getApplicationDataDirectory(), 'assessment.db'));

var tbl_name = db.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' ORDER BY name");

var row_name = db.execute("SELECT * FROM " + tbl_name);


//This is a table I've hard-coded into the html page
var tbl = document.getElementById('tbl');

while (tbl_name.isValidRow()) {


while (row_name.isValidRow()) {
var td = document.createElement('td');
var row = row_name.fieldByName();
td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(row));
tr.appendChild(td);
tbl.appendChild(tr);
row_name.next();   
};

//end row while loop

var tr = document.createElement('tr');
var name = tbl_name.fieldByName('name');
tr.appendChild(document.createTextNode(name));
tbl.appendChild(tr);
tbl_name.next();   
};
//end table while loop


}
```

I've been racking my brain trying to get this to work, and thought maybe someone on here would know how to point me in the right direction.

Comment: You have a dangling `+` operator at the `row_name` line. It's probably a typo but as is it is a syntax error.

Comment: @slebetman I've removed the extra + operator from the end of the row_name line. Thanks for the tip. Still not working though